# Custom render how to scroll and tap

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am usingand I need the user to be able to do both tap which will open popup and scroll down. However now I am able to do  only one of these two activites as seems to be unresponsive to Tapgesture.

I implemented this solution [not possible and subsituted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62671402/tap-in-webview-not-possible-and-subsituted-with-boxview-now-scroll-doesnt-work) however now I cannot scroll because the is funny enough too responsive so I get pop up straight away.

```
            _webView.Touch += (object sender, TouchEventArgs eventArgs) => {


                if (eventArgs.Event.Action == Android.Views.MotionEventActions.Down)
                {
                    var webview = Element as ExtendedWebView;
                    
                    webview.OnTouched();
                }
            };
        }

    }

 <Grid x:Name="scroll">
                                  
                                        <controls:ExtendedWebView x:Name="czExplanation" Source="{Binding CZ, Mode=OneWay}" Touched="PopUp">

                                        </controls:ExtendedWebView>
                                   

                                </Grid>

  public ExtendedWebView()
        {
        }

        public event EventHandler Touched;

        public void OnTouched() =>
        Touched?.Invoke(this, null);
        public ICommand PannedCommand
        {
            set { SetValue(PannedCommandProperty, value); }
            get { return (ICommand)GetValue(PannedCommandProperty); }
        }
        public static readonly BindableProperty PannedCommandProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(PannedCommand), typeof(ICommand), typeof(ExtendedWebView));
```

**Update**

```
<controls:ExtendedWebView x:Name="webView" Source="{Binding CZ, Mode=OneWay}" PannedCommand="{Binding PanCommand}" Touched="webView_Touched">
                                            </controls:ExtendedWebView>

 public class ExtendedWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer
    {
        public static int _webViewHeight;
        static ExtendedWebView _xwebView = null;
        public WebView _webView;
        bool isScroll;

        public ExtendedWebViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        class ExtendedWebViewClient : WebViewClient
        {

            WebView _webView;



            public async override void OnPageFinished(WebView view, string url)
            {
                try
                {
                    _webView = view;
                    if (_xwebView != null)
                    {

                        view.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
                        await Task.Delay(100);
                        string result = await _xwebView.EvaluateJavaScriptAsync("(function(){return document.body.scrollHeight;})()");
                        _xwebView.HeightRequest = Convert.ToDouble(result);


                    }
                    base.OnPageFinished(view, url);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{ex.Message}");
                }
            }
            public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(Android.Webkit.WebView view, IWebResourceRequest request)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.WebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            _xwebView = e.NewElement as ExtendedWebView;
            _webView = Control;

            if (e.OldElement == null)
            {
                _webView.SetWebViewClient(new ExtendedWebViewClient());
            }

            _webView.Touch += (object sender, TouchEventArgs eventArgs) =>
            {


                switch (e.Event.Action)
                {

         
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked your sample , you could improve it like following .

#### in xaml

Now you don't need to use **BoxView** any more .

```
<extendedtest:ExtendedWebView x:Name="webView" PannedCommand="{Binding PanCommand}" Touched="webView_Touched"/>
```

#### in Custom Renderer

```
 bool isScroll;
```

```
 _webView.Touch += _webView_Touch;
```

```
private void _webView_Touch(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
        {

            var webview = Element as ExtendedWebView;

            bool isMove=true;

            Console.WriteLine(e.Event.Action);

            switch (e.Event.Action)
            {

                case Android.Views.MotionEventActions.Down:

                    isScroll = false;
                    break;

                case Android.Views.MotionEventActions.Move:
                   
                    isScroll = true;

                    if(isMove)
                    {
                        isMove = false;
                        webview.PannedCommand?.Execute(null);
                        
                    }

                    break;


                case Android.Views.MotionEventActions.Up:
                    
                    if(!isScroll)
                    {
                        webview.OnTouched();
                    }
                    
                    
                    break;

                default:

                    break;

            }
```

#### in ContentPage

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
    

       

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var htmlSource = new HtmlWebViewSource();
            htmlSource.Html = @"<html><body>
  <h1>Xamarin.Forms</h1>
  <p>Welcome to WebView.</p>
 <p>Welcome to WebView.</p> <p>Welcome to WebView.</p> 
<p>Welcome to WebView.</p> <p>Welcome to WebView.</p> <p>Welcome to WebView.</p> 
<p>Welcome to WebView.</p> <p>Welcome to WebView.</p>
 <p>Welcome to WebView.</p>
  </body></html>";
            

        }

        

        private void webView_Touched(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Navigation.PushAsync(new secondPage());
        }

        
    }
```

Comment: i am getting an error that webView_Touched was not found with correct signature

Comment: Jesus :D ok, the scroll doesnt work but i guess i have to debug the render why it doesnt work

Comment: You add tap , pan and scroll in the webview at same time . It might be conflict with each other .

Comment: i am not adding tap anymore, just what you suggested   <controls:ExtendedWebView x:Name="webView" Source="{Binding CZ, Mode=OneWay}" PannedCommand="{Binding PannedCommand}" Touched="webView_Touched">
                                            </controls:ExtendedWebView>

Comment: I will provide a full sample with the improve part to you tomorrow . Sorry for waiting .

Comment: Just so you know, it works i can see the event in the output however the Content of my webview is not moving at all.

Comment: If you just want to implement it in Android , you could use `Focused` event in webview instead of Tap event .

Comment: Focus on the binding of the text or the actual pop up navigation